# Sticky cell and Fixed Div overlay issue

Tags: css, overlay, sticky, mudblazor

I have an issue using CSS property *position: sticky* and a fixed div used for overlay.

I'm using MudBlazor library for developing a website, but I think the problem isn't relative to the library.

I made an example reproducing issue:

```cs
<style>
    .mud-overlay {
        background-color: red;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
</style>
<MudSimpleTable Class="mud-table-root mud-xs-table flex-1" Dense="true" Hover="true" Striped="true" FixedHeader="true">

    <thead class="mud-table-head">
        <tr class="mud-table-row">
            <th class="mud-table-cell text-center">
                ID
            </th>
            <th class="mud-table-cell">
                Name
            </th>
            <th class="mud-table-cell" style="position: sticky; right: 0;">
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="mud-table-body">
        @for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            var tmp = i;
            <tr>
                <th class="mud-table-cell text-center">
                    @i
                </th>
                <th class="mud-table-cell">
                    Name @i
                </th>
                <th class="mud-table-cell" style="position: sticky; right: 0; background-color: yellow;">
                    <MudMenu Dense="true" Size="Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert">
                        <MudMenuItem Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Edit" IconSize="Size.Small">Action #1</MudMenuItem>
                        <MudMenuItem Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Check" IconSize="Size.Small">Action #2</MudMenuItem>
                    </MudMenu>
                </th>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</MudSimpleTable>



@code {
    public string Text { get; set; } = "????";
    public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Click Me";
    public int ButtonClicked { get; set; }

    void ButtonOnClick()
    {
        ButtonClicked += 1;
        Text = $"Awesome x {ButtonClicked}";
        ButtonText = "Click Me Again";
    }
}
```

The example above can be run here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEcHkyuVnVykRptC

To make what happens clear I made the overlay red.
As you can see, when I click on a three-dots to open menu, an overlay is raised and it should cover everything but the menu.

The problem is that this overlay cover everything but the cell with *position: sticky* below the cell where the menu has been opened.

How can I solve it? I would like that **everything** but the menu goes under the overlay.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Sorry Rob, I thought the link was enough. Thanks Bart for updating my question with the example.